# Extract from the same column different queries , resuls are diplayed in separate columns

Tags: database, postgresql, join, union

I have the following table robot_state :

```
section  robotid       date                 active

  area1|    11   | 2014-08-09 02:40:09 |         1
  area1|    11   | 2014-08-09 02:55:50 |         0
  area3|    01   | 2014-08-09 03:40:09 |         1
  area3|    11   | 2014-08-10 00:15:50 |         1
  area1|    11   | 2014-08-10 02:40:09 |         1
  area1|    11   | 2014-08-12 00:15:50 |         0
```

For specific section and robot id I would like to extract the dates when the robot was active and  inactive using two separate columns. For example for section area1 and

robotid=11, I should obtain this result:

```
     robot_ON         |    robot_OFF 
  2014-08-09 02:40:09 | 2014-08-09 02:55:50
  2014-08-10 02:40:09 | 2014-08-12 00:15:50
```

Any help how I can write the query. I tried with union:

```
select date from robot_state where (active=1 and section ='area1' and robotid=11) 
union 
select date from robot_state where (active=0 and section ='area1' and robotid=11);
```

but the result was displayed in one column. The idea behind to have two columns is to compute later the time difference when the robot was active at each time it starts working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to join robot_state on itself, something along these lines (I have not tried it)

```
select on.date, off.date from (
  select date
  from robot_state 
  where active=1 and section ='area1' and robotid=11
) as On
inner join (
  select date
  from robot_state 
  where active=0 and section ='area1' and robotid=11
) as off 
on off.date = (select min(date) 
               from robot_state
               where active=0 and section ='area1' and robotid=11
               and date > on.date)
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot , I tried it and it is working except that "on.date" and "off.date" were not accepted, I used robotOn.date and robotOff.date instead.